# I2C Communication Matlab - FDC1004

Tags: i2c, matlab

I have a ProtoCentral FDC1004 board (datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/fdc1004.pdf) connected to an Arduino. I am then trying to connect to the system via matlab.

I have found the address (0x50) using *addrs = scanI2CBus(a)* and I am now trying to read measurements from it.

Page 15 of the datasheet says the following to trigger measurements:

```
 1. Setting REPEAT (Register 0x0C:bit[8]) to 0.
 2. Setting the corresponding MEAS_x field (Register 0x0C:bit[7:4]) to 1.
    – For example, to trigger a single measurement of Measurement 2 at a rate of 100S/s, 
    set Address 0x0C to 0x0540.
```

**Q1**: How do I work out where the value "0x0540" comes from?

**Q2**: I don't seem to be able to write this value, I'm able to write other values to this register and read them back however. How can I write 0x0540 to this register?

My matlab script is as follows:

```
a = arduino('COM7', 'Uno', 'Libraries', 'I2C');
capdev = device(a,'I2CAddress',0x50);

writeRegister(capdev, 0x0C, 0x0540,'uint16');
readRegister(capdev,0x0C,'uint16')
value1 = readRegister(capdev,0x02,'uint16')
value2 = readRegister(capdev,0x03,'uint16')
```

readRegister(capdev,0x0C,'uint16') simply displays the last value I wrote to this register during testing (eg 3)

0x02 and 0x03 are supposedly where measurement 2 is stored. These read as 0.

**Q3**: Any idea what I'm doing wrong, or how to implement this correctly?

Thank you!

Comment: Q1 ... see Table 5 ... convert 0x0540 to binary

Comment: Q1 - converting to decimal (which i need for matlab) gives 1344. I still cannot write this in matlab (returns "0" when I read it back)

Comment: Matlab seems happy for me to specify in whatever (https://uk.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/arduinoio/ref/writeregister.html#d117e17865) but I can't get this value to write in any format for some reason

Comment: why do you believe that you can read back the value that you wrote to register `0x0c`?

Comment: regarding Q1, why are you converting to decimal? ... have you forgotten what you asked in Q1?

Comment: - Why do I believe I can read it back? a) because I can read it back when I write test data to it (small integers, 0-15) b) because why wouldn't I be able to

Comment: - Why convert to decimal? Because I still need to write it in matlab which I can't seem to do with the hex value. The matlab examples I've seen write to registers using decimal so that seemed like a good thing to try. Alas, that didn't seem to work either

Comment: converting to decimal has nothing to do with Q1

Comment: `Why do I believe I can read it back?` ... `a)` makes sense ... try values up to 0xff .... `b)` you cannot assume that all registers read back what you wrote to them ... always refer to the device datasheet to make sure